# Subset SAM/BAM file in R

Tags: r, subset, bioinformatics, bioconductor, bam

I have a BAM file with lots of reads.
I can load it into R with `scanBam` from `Rsamtools`.

However, I only need a subset of reads.
I have a `character` vector with the qnames I am interested in.

`scanBam` returns a list with 1 element which is a list with 13 elements which contain data for all the thousands of reads.

How can I subset this object by `qname` preserving the structure?
I was not able to find anything in the manual or online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably more convenient to input the data with GenomicAlignments::readGAlignments, including the qname by specifying param=ScanBamParam(what="qname") as an argument. You could then subset with %in%. Here's a more complete example, using one of the [ExperimentData](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___ExperimentData) packages

```
library(GenomicAlignments)
library(RNAseqData.HNRNPC.bam.chr14)

fname <- RNAseqData.HNRNPC.bam.chr14_BAMFILES[1]    
want <- c("ERR127306.11930623", "ERR127306.24720935",
    "ERR127306.23706011", "ERR127306.22418829", "ERR127306.13372247",
    "ERR127306.20686334", "ERR127306.11412145", "ERR127306.4711647",
    "ERR127306.7479582", "ERR127306.12737243")
aln <- readGAlignments(fname, param=ScanBamParam(what="qname"))
aln[mcols(aln)$qname %in% want]
```

BAM files are of course big, and the qnames are a big part of that; it often makes sense to iterate through the file in chunks. This is enabled (in the current Rsamtools) with yieldReduce, where one provides BamFile with yieldSize set to a reasonable (e.g., 1M) number of reads, a MAP function to input a chunk of data and process it (e.g., filtering the unwanted reads), an (optional) REDUCE function to concatenate results, and an (optional) DONE function to indicate when the iteration is done. The solution looks like (yieldSize is artificially small, to allow illustration  with the sample data):

```
bfl <- BamFile(fname, yieldSize=100000)  ## larger, e.g., 1M-5M
MAP <- function(bfl, want) {
    ## message("tick")
    aln <- readGAlignments(bfl, param=ScanBamParam(what="qname"))
    if (length(aln) == 0)
        NA                          # semaphore -- DONE
    else
        aln[mcols(aln)$qname %in% want]
}
REDUCE <- c
DONE <- function(x) identical(x, NA)
result <- yieldReduce(bfl, MAP, REDUCE, DONE, want=want)
```

One could adopt a similar approach using scanBam, but the data structure (list-of-lists) is more complicated to deal with:

```
x <- scanBam(fname, param=ScanBamParam(what=c("qname", "pos")))
keep <- lapply(lapply(x, "[[", "qname"), "%in%", want)
result <- Map(function(elts, keep) {
    lapply(elts, "[", keep)
}, x, keep)
```

This could also be used with yieldReduce.

If you're interested in creating a *new* bam file with the filtered reads, then

```
filter_factory <- function(want) {
    list(KeepQname = function(x) x$qname %in% want)
}
filter <- FilterRules(filter_factory(want))
dest <- filterBam(fname, tempfile(), filter=filter,
                  param=ScanBamParam(what="qname"))
readGAlignments(dest)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed answer. All your suggestion seem to do  what I want. The 3rd is actually a working version of what I tried when I decided that there must to be a better way. Your second soltion is quite elaborate and I have to process only one BAM file, so I don't bother waiting 30sec but it is good to know for future work. Your last suggestion is what I found in the manual but I explicitly don't want to write to a new file (I would use samtools directly in this case instead of wrinting an R script). Can you comment on the benefits of your 1st suggestion over my simple solution?

Comment: @sg-lecram your solution is good; the main difference is that GAlignments knows about ranges, so for instance if you were further interested in specific regions of interest `roi = GRanges(...)` it would be straight-forward to `subsetByOverlaps(aln, roi)` or `countOverlaps()` or any of the other very convenient range-based operations. There is probably no real cost to using yieldReduce, most of the time is spent on input (which has to be done anyway) and down-stream processing; yieldReduce is very useful for managing memory, esp. in conjunction with parallel processing of multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using `subset(DataFrame(scanBam(bam_file)[[1]]),qname %in% qname_vector)`.
This does not keep the exact same structure (list of list) but all the information is kept and easily accessible.